# ESP32 websocket client frame fragmentation configuration for binary data

Tags: websocket, esp32, esp-idf

I am attempting to send camera frames to a web socket server from an ESP32 with a camera. I am using the ESP-IDF to implement the client web socket on the device. Specifically, I am using: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_websocket_client.html.

I have noticed an issue where the server does not receive full frames from the device. I did some digging, read through RFC6455 and became aware of the concept of frame fragmentation. My thinking now is that the camera frames (640 x 480 pixels) need to be fragmented before being sent. I read through the ESP-IDF docs and only saw one mention of fragmentation.

I feel comfortable enough to implement it myself, but it seems that there is no way to set the FIN bit, OPCODE, or any other parameters of the header described by RFC6455 using the ESP-IDF web socket client library.

Does any one have any idea how these parameters can be set, or if there is some way to enable native frame fragmentation on the device?

Comment: [Looks like the message is already fragmented, if it's bigger than `buffer_size`.](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/09f5c1d32ed3db68dc1c593a6f7c52c45b388cc9/components/esp_websocket_client/esp_websocket_client.c#L855-L876)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/09f5c1d32ed3db68dc1c593a6f7c52c45b388cc9/components/esp_websocket_client/esp_websocket_client.c#L855-L876), it appears that the message is already being fragmented, if the message exceeds the size of `buffer_size`.

The default size of `buffer_size` is 1024 bytes. You can change it in the config.

```c
const esp_websocket_client_config_t websocket_cfg = {
    ...
    .buffer_size = 512,
};
```